# Excel return multipls cell behind one

Tags: excel, cells

I need to create a vlookup to find a cell and returns all cells that are underneath, in the example:

[image]

I need to find the color and return all cells that are down, can you help me?

Comment: this is the way =INDEX($E$2:$T$2;MATCH($A$3;$E$1:$T$1;0)+1)

Comment: Dont think so, cells seem to be merged and there are several cells down...